# How to open a URL in a new Tab using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to open a URL in new tab instead of new window programatically?

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="url">` but it's up to the user's browser preferences.

Comment: Thats not programatically...

Comment: @FabianCook It's a programming language syntax... so I'd call it programmatic!

Comment: Mmmm, actually in this question the people answer most well the question instead the question marked as link in the top

Answer (score 527):

Use `window.open()`:

```
var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else {
    //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

Depending on the browsers implementation this will work

There is nothing you can do to make it open in a window rather than a tab.

Comment: What does `_blank` do in this call?

Comment: It's a special name of a browser window that will create a new window every time, alternatively you could use a specific name like "login_screen", if the window is already loaded it will reload the content with the URL you have provided

Comment: `window.open()` would cause the popup warning which is an unwanted user experience. Instead introduce a hidden `<a href="" target="_blank" id="click_me"
></a>` somewhere and perform a click using `.click()` For ex: `document.getElementById('click_me').click()`

Answer (score 219):

This is as simple as this.

```
window.open('_link is here_', 'name');
```

Function description:

`name` is a name of the window. Following names are supported:

- `_blank` - URL is loaded into a **new tab**. *This is default.*
- `_parent` - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- `_self` - URL replaces the current page
- `_top` - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

Comment: For security, one could add the "noopener" and "noreferrer" window features: window.open("url", "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");

Answer (score 76):

if you mean to opening all links on new tab, try to use this jquery

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Comment: @Vicky is your `a` element appended by other event? May you need to change `.click` with `.on('click'`

Comment: i am trying to implement same logic using your answer which works but when i try to right click and do open link in new tab it doesnt. any idea how can i fix that?

Answer (score 47):

```
 var url = "http://www.example.com";
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 28):

You can easily create a new tab; do like the following:

```
function newTab() {
     var form = document.createElement("form");
     form.method = "GET";
     form.action = "http://www.example.com";
     form.target = "_blank";
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi dude.. when I open like this im getting like firefox prevented this site from opening popup....

Comment: Amend your implementation to be user-driven (i.e. Click a link) and not self-executing (i.e. On page load) ... then praise the righteous popup blocker

Answer (score 15):

I know your question does not specify if you are trying to open all a tags in a new window or only the external links.

But in case you only want external links to open in a new tab you can do this:

```
$( 'a[href^="http://"]' ).attr( 'target','_blank' )
$( 'a[href^="https://"]' ).attr( 'target','_blank' )
```

Comment: It treats www.google.com as an internal link.. How can i open it in a new tab ? or Add http