# Why does the following script not open a new tab or page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript function to navigate away from my website and to another website. I am also trying to open a new page when the button is clicked but instead it navigates on `self` instead of `blank`. Why does this happen?

HTML

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
<input style="font-size:large;" id="btamen" type="button" value="Visit Website">
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btamen").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'

    link.target = '_blank';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just use google ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line: `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'` will always replace current page with the new url.

I don't know what is `link` in the next page, but that code won't even execute because the page redirects and the context is lost.

If you want it like that, then do this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank').focus();
```

Also, you cannot guarantee its opening as browser *might* block it. Sort of kinda pop up blocker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can control it to open in a new tab. So you have to work around, what I did is:

```
<a href="" target="_blank" id="btamen_link">
  <button type="button" id="btamen">
    Click
  </button>
</a>
```

And the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btamen').click(function(){
      $('#btamen_link').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
      $('#btamen_link').click();
    });
  });
</script>
```