# How to open new tab using onclick="javascript:location.href"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to open a new tab using "**javascript:location.href**". I can't use other methods to open the link because it needs to get the ID of a certain member of my website when it loads. I also can't make a javascript function because I have more than one link to open.

```
target="_blank" //didn't work
```

Here's a piece of my code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:location.href='website.com' + location.search"><a/>
```

If there are other ways to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Not possible that `_blank` would not work

Comment: keep this in a function and use `window.open`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not use window.open .

```
<a onclick="window.open('website.com' + location.search)"><a/>
```

Comment: this will open a new windows not tab

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama: It is not necessary. In modern browsers, window.open will open in a new tab rather than a popup. Plus it depends on browser settings

Comment: `window.open('your url', '_blank'); `, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852472/3256489

Comment: Worked like a charm, great

Answer (score 2):

ofcourse your scenario is not that simple i've written below, but have a look up my snippet. it dynamically extracts a value and appends it to anchor. which will be opened in new tab.

```js
var id = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML
document.getElementById('pseudo-dynamism').href += '?id='+ id
```

```html
  <div id="main">
    <div id="member-details" class="question" data-answered="False">
       <span id="id">23</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://example.com" id="pseudo-dynamism" target="_blank">Click</a> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this It will open new window.

```
 `<button 
onclick="window.open
(this.href,'popUpWindow','height=600,width=600,left=10,top=10,,
scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); 
return false;" >
new window
</button>`
```

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP users**

```
$url = 'stackoverflow.com';
<a onclick="window.open(<?php echo $url ?> + location.search)">Website<a/>
```