# Angular 2 - Redirect to an external URL and open in a new tab

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to Open a new page when user clicks on a link. I can't use Angular 2 Router, because it doesn't have any functionalities to redirect to an external URL.

so, i'm using window.location.href="...";

html code:

```
<button (click)="onNavigate()">Google</tn-submenu-link>
```

typescript code:

```
onNavigate(){
        //this.router.navigateByUrl("https://www.google.com");
        window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
    }
```

But how can I open it in a new tab? when using window.location.href ?

Comment: If you can narrow it down to using Javascript, this should be a javascript question, not Angular2. Can you apply this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery ?

Comment: @HarryNinh Angular 2 and 4 do not expose the `window` object inside a component (while you can get-away with using the `window` global, it's preferred to perform platform-specific tasks (like using the `window` object, which differs between browsers) using an Angular Service.

Answer (score 162):

```
onNavigate(){
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Chrome is blocking popups when I use this method. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @sunnyiitkgp `window.open()` must be called within a callback which is triggered by a user action (example onclick).

Comment: @gokcand it is obvious, but it doesn't change the situation cause still is blocked as mentioned above.

Comment: Nothing beats good old vanilla javascript :)

Comment: Chrome blocks window.open() that is not "called within a callback which is triggered by a user action (example onclick)" as @gokcand stated, to try to help end the bad-old-days when a person would browse to a webpage and twenty windows would pop open on their screen.  They don't want to party like it's 1995.

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 40):

One caveat on using `window.open()` is that if the url that you pass to it doesn't have `http://` or `https://` in front of it, angular treats it as a route.

To get around this, test if the url starts with `http://` or `https://` and append it if it doesn't.

```
let url: string = '';
if (!/^http[s]?:\/\//.test(this.urlToOpen)) {
    url += 'http://';
}

url += this.urlToOpen;
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: I've been searching on and off for this for a week. In Angular 4 this works for me as a short term solution: <a href="https://{{url}}">, when it was treated as a route before. Thanks!

Comment: cant `//` suffice?
eg:
`window.open(``//${this.urlToOpen}``, '_blank')`

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 19):

in HTML:

```
<a class="main-item" (click)="onNavigate()">Go to URL</a>
```

OR

```
<button class="main-item" (click)="onNavigate()">Go to URL</button>
```

in TS file:

```
onNavigate(){
    // your logic here.... like set the url 
    const url = 'https://www.google.com';
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 10):

Another possible solution is:

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.target = '_blank';
link.href = 'https://www.google.es';
link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
link.click();
```

Comment: This method opens Link in new tab.  "  window.open(url, '_blank'); " open popup which is normally blocked by Chrome

Comment: Don't modify the DOM if using Angular, this is not jquery. This would run out of the Angular change detection cycle and can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue more globally, here is another way using a **directive**:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[hrefExternalUrl]"
})
export class HrefExternalUrlDirective {
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let url: string = (<any>event.currentTarget).getAttribute("href");

    if (url && url.indexOf("http") === -1) {
      url = `//${url}`;
    }

    window.open(url, "_blank");
  }
}
```

then it's as simple as using it like this:

```
<a [href]="url" hrefExternalUrl> Link </a>
```

and don't forget to declare the directive in your module.

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 5):

you can do like this in your typescript code

```
onNavigate(){
var location="https://google.com",
}
```

In your html code add an anchor tag and pass that variable(location)

```
<a href="{{location}}" target="_blank">Redirect Location</a>
```

Suppose you have url like this `www.google.com` without `http` and you are not getting redirected to the given url then add `http://` to the `location` like this

```
var location = 'http://'+ www.google.com
```

Answer (score 5):

I want to share with you one more solution if you have absolute part in the URL

SharePoint solution with `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}`

HTML:

```
<button (click)="onNavigate()">Google</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
onNavigate()
{
    let link = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/SiteAssets/Pages/help.aspx#/help`;
    window.open(link, "_blank");
}
```

and url will be opened in new tab.

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = "https://yourURL.com";
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.opener = null;
    win.focus();
```

This will resolve the issue, here you don't need to use DomSanitizer. Its work for me

Comment: Please, don't use window global object directly in Angular, see my answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

we can use target = blank to open in new tab

```
 <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="blank">click Here </a>
```

Comment: Well done! This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here use javascript global objects in Angular. This is not recommended, it won't work if you have SSR, and can cause unexpected and undesired behavior.

There are different ways to access the window object: you can use directly the DOCUMENT token included in Angular, with its `deafultView` property, or create a factory to return a WINDOW token, similar to DOCUMENT token. I'll describe the first option here, since it's simpler. There is plenty of information around to implement the second option:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly documentRef: Document) { }

onNavigate(){
    this.documentRef.defaultView.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
}
```