# Redirect to external url in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to redirect to an external url after some action. Please refer my code

```
            this.http.get(this.apiurl+'api/insert.php?did='+this.did).subscribe(data=>{
                  var jsonData = data.json();    
                  let url = jsonData.urlpass;
// redirect to this url like https://flipkart.com with my affilate params
window.open(url ,'_blank'); 
    });
```

this `window.open(url ,'_blank');` shows the popup blocker.

So I tried like this

```
<a #myDiv id="anchorID" href="url here" target="_blank"></a>
$("#anchorID")[0].click();
```

But this click event is not triggered inside the subscribe method.

If I use `var newWin = window.open();
              newWin.location = url_pass;`

It creates the error as `Cannot assign to 'location' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

I want to open this external url in new window with out popupblocker issue.

Please help anyone.

Comment: Window open expects the url to be passed... and jQuery... have you tried angular tutorials?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Angular 2 - Redirect to an external URL and open in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775017/angular-2-redirect-to-an-external-url-and-open-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2

Comment: is updated answer worked for you ??

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this ,

component.html , add link to html in hidden mode

```
  <a #popupLink class="btn-excel" (click)='popup()' 
                                       style="display:none">
    <span>Dummy link</span>
  </a>
```

component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('popupLink') popupLink;

   popup() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
  }

  //some where from code
  popupLink.click();
```

Comment: @SamHanson - cna you try solution now ??

Comment: Yes. It shows error on popupLink.click(); line. Shall need to define popuplink . I am new to angular. Please give some directions

Comment: @SamHanson - updated just cause problem with variable name , i am trying to figure out if this resolves issue or not as it working for me, it good if you create link in html which is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var newWin = win.open('some_url');
```