# Angular Route.navigate in new tab

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have to perform some business logic in my component and based on that result i need to navigate to a new item.

`this.router.navigate(['../NewProduct', response.id], { relativeTo: this.route });`

Requirement states that it should open in a new window. I know i can achieve this with a routerLink in html. But i should go straight to the page and can't use this method.

I can't find any way to add a parameter to the navigate function to go to a blank tab.

Is there any way this can be accomplished with Angular Routing?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775017/angular-2-redirect-to-an-external-url-and-open-in-a-new-tab/51574404) is relevant here. Maybe try `window.open(url)`.

Comment: this is not available from the component