# Window location target _blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Hi I have this problem with window location target and cannot solve it. I'm doing some GA tracking for links through out my page and I want to add target location _ blank. the code is this

```
$(".ga_track").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var label = $(this).attr('data-description');
  ga('send', 'event', 'Link Clicked', 'Click Details', label, {
    'hitCallback': function () {
      window.location.href = href;
      window.location.target = blank;
    }
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this function

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

And duplicate question:
[How to open a URL in a new Tab using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally incorrect.

**You are doing window.location.href which means, you are doing it in current window then how can you set it to target?**. That is why there is no such target property in window.location.

If you want any such behavior create one anchor ("a") element and then set target and href attributes on that and then trigger click on that.

or use **window.open for another window**

Answer (score 0):

You should try like

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="ga(...);window.open(URL, name, specs, replace);return false;"> </a>
```