# How to open new tab by write some text?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I was looking for some information about how to open link by writing exact word, in my case it will be "film". I want to open new link by writing on  website in input elemtent word - "film".

Can you give me some hints?

Thank you, 
Megi

Comment: Writing where on website ? Some input element ?

Comment: I want to open new link by writing on website in input elemtent word - "film".

Comment: @MagdalenaDering Please add your comment to your question. This can prevent missunderstandings.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @Kia It is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onInput` or also use `onkeyup` Event to open a new tab with `window.open`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter keyword: <input id="keywordinput" type="text" value="notfilm" oninput="checkForFilm()">

<script>
function checkForFilm() 
{
    if(document.getElementById('keywordinput').value == 'film')
    {
      var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
      if (win) 
      {          
          win.focus();
      } 
      else 
      {          
          alert('Please allow popups for this website');
      }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used the example above, done by Kia and I changed to my needs. Everything is working really good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onkeyup` event.

```js
function openLink(e){
  if(e.value == 'film'){
      var new_window = window.open('http://abc.xyz/', '_blank'); // Replace with your link. 
      if(new_window){          
          win.focus();
      }
      else{
          alert("Allow popups from your browser settings.");
      }
  }
}
```

```html
Enter word : <input type="text" name="input_name" id="input_id" value="" onkeyup="openLink(this);" />
```