# Open a src a script in a new window

Tags: javascript

I would like to edit a Booking script, I want that when I press the button "check the availability" that it opens the link in a new window. How can I do it? Because it goes outside of my page to the Booking page.

Thank you.
   http://www.booking.com/general.html?tmpl=bookit;aid=330843;lang=es;hotel_id=18530;cc1=es;hotel_page=flora-parc>

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As your question is written, I can't figure out what you are trying to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery