# Why window onload event doesn't get triggered on recursive call?

Tags: javascript, recursion, window.open

The window onload event was not triggering while a new tab being opened. The following is the sample code for doing the same. Here a list of URLs is being tried to open in separate same tab one after another, as the onload event is not being triggered, the recursive calls are not being happening.

```js
var urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843', 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/19851782', 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/726761'];

function opennewtab(i) {
  var w = window.open(urls[i], 'so', '');
  if (w) {
    w.onload = function() {
      opennewtab(i + 1);
    }
  }
};

opennewtab(0);
```

All are in same domain. Please paste the code snippet in the browser developer tools in same page here.

Comment: You can't set variables in a page from a different domain.

Comment: @Barmar It's the same domain.

Comment: Also, when you open those pages, they don't load your JavaScript, so the function `opennewtab()` doesn't exist there.

Comment: The original page is in the `stackoverflow.com` domain?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, Please try this in very same page here in browser developer tools.

Comment: I guess, this might be because onload event is triggered before actual code event listening code is being executed.

Comment: That could be. JavaScript is single-thread in one window, but each window has its own thread.

Comment: You could try opening the window to a blank URL, add the `onload` property, then redirect the window to the target URL, which should trigger a second event.

Comment: Wow what a mess... I spent about two hours on this and still didn't succeed. Here are a few points that may help someone with more time than myself. `open(url, "name")` always returns the same Window instance. However, the Events you attach to it will get removed at each `unload` event. Given this, I made [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/hGOpTGovhrhWXZ70CAXz?p=preview), which actually works... if you are not focused on that window! That is, you need to come back to the main window for it to work... That's a very weird behavior, but given both Chrome and FF do the same, I'd assume it's standard...

Answer (score 0):

why not use the promises?
I have not tested, but it should look something like this:

```
const urls = 
    [ 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843'
    , 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/19851782'
    , 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/726761'
    ] 

function Load_URL(url) {
  return new Promise(res=>{
    let w = window.open(url, 'so', '')
    w.addEventListener('load', res)
  }) 
}

for (let url_x of urls) await Load_URL(url_x)
```